# Skip JHipster integration tests using gradle

Tags: jhipster

I am using JHipster 3.4.0 with gradle.

Excuse me for newbie questions.

There are times when I don't trust hot reloads and want to do full clean build.
However, executing 'build' task always lead to running integration tests.

Doing something like

```
   test {
      //  include '**/*UnitTest*'
      //  include '**/*IntTest*'

      // ignoreFailures true
      // reports.html.enabled = false
   }
```

in build.gradle doesn't help.

- So how do I skip integration tests for full clean build?
- And just to confirm, the task to do full clean build is 'build' right?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: To partially answer my own questions. Just found out the command line

Answer (score 2):

To partially answer my own questions. Just found out the command line

gradle build -x test

will do the trick. But I don't think that answer my question of why comment out test task above doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the test are still running, when commenting the includes is, that test task has default values (if you don't overwrite them). So all classes in `src/main/test` are used as test classes. Your way by passing a command line parameter is the way to go.